# How do I use local auth and qr code scanner in the same flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I building a flutter app that scans bar codes and also uses biometric auth in it. The problem is for package local_auth

MainActivity.kt should be like

```
  public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
  // ...
  }
```

but for scaning bar codes MainActivity.kt should be like

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

else it don't work. How do I use them both in the same project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

barcode_scan2 should work fine with FlutterFragmentActivity. I am using barcode_scan2 along with local_auth from long time using FlutterFragmentActivity.

If you are getting any specific error then paste it here.

Comment: thank you for your answer 
 This plugin is written in Kotlin. Therefore, i need to add Kotlin support to my project.
now I am looking for ways to add Kotlin support to that project